# Get folder name of unzipped .tar.gz file

Tags: python, tar

I've got a python script that extracts everything from a `.tar.gz` file and then works on the extracted files.

The python code that extracts the item is currently:

```
    tar = tarfile.open(input_file)
    tar.extractall(output_location)
    tar.close()
```

Where `input file` is the tarball, and `output_location` is the folder to which I'm extracting the tarball.

The tarball is created via `tar -czf (output filename) (input folder)` , so the compressed materials are thus guaranteed to be inside a folder, and the only top-level item in the tarball will be that one folder.  (The output location is not necessarily empty.) *Normally*, the extracted folder is named `course`, but it *could* theoretically be named anything.

Is there a way to get the name of that top-level folder, either before or after it's extracted?

Failing that, it's ok for me to rename the folder. Is there a way to extract all the compressed stuff *inside* the tarball's top-level folder so that I can put it in a folder I name myself? I could unzip everything into a new folder and then pull everything down one level of hierarchy, and that would be equivalent, but it feels like shooting a gnat with a cannon.

Comment: Please show some python code that illustrates how you are extracting these files? Are you extracting them into memory or onto disk?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Code added. I'm currently extracting to disk. If it matters, the max output folder size is about a gigabyte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html#os.listdir). In your case, a list with a single item is returned, the item being the name of the directory you need.

```
import os
dir_name = os.listdir(output_folder)[0]
```

or like this, which raises unless you have a single entry as expected:

```
dir_name, = os.listdir(output_folder)
```

EDIT

To simply get the names of the files/directories in the archive, use `tar.getnames()`.  If you know you only have one, get it using `tar.getnames()[0]`.

Comment: My apologies; the `output_folder` in my question is the folder than I'm extracting to, not the folder inside the tarfile. This solution seems like it would find the newly created folder if I knew its name, which I don't. The location to which I'm extracting the tarball is not necessarily empty. Let me see if I can rewrite for better clarity; it's a tough question to write.

Comment: @ColinFredericks you can get the names using `tar.getnames()`

Comment: That seems to have worked! `tar.getnames()[0]` seems to be the top-level folder. (Though sometimes with a dot and underscore for some reason.) Post this as an answer so I can pick it.

Comment: Tagging @shx2 - your method worked and you should post it as an answer. Thanks!